# angular filter empty array in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-filters

I have this array of objects

```
var list = [{
    "questionId": 1,
    "correctChoiceIds": [],
    "choiceId": 0,
    "number": 1
}, {
    "questionId": 1,
    "correctChoiceIds": [1234, 4567],
    "choiceId": 0,
    "number": 2,
}, {
    "questionId": 2,
    "correctChoiceIds": [],
    "choiceId": 0,
    "number": 3
}];

//This filter gives me an array with list[0] and list[1]
var filterQuestion = $filter('filter')(list, { questionId: 1 }, true);
```

I want to filter all those with an empty array for their `correctChoiceIds`.

```
var filterNoCorrectChoice= $filter('filter')(list, { correctChoiceIds: [] }, true);
```

This is what I came up with but it simply gives me nothing. I'm not sure if this is the right way or why it results to nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/g894mML8igcJ34ERiYUG?p=preview)

Use the filter like this,

```
  var filterNoCorrectChoice= $filter('filter')(list,function(item) {
        // must have array, and array must be empty
        return item.correctChoiceIds && item.correctChoiceIds.length === 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

method filter native

```
var filterQuestion = list.filter(function(el){ return el.correctChoiceIds.length<1; });
// result
console.log(filterQuestion);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to filter all those with an empty array for their `correctChoiceIds`

You don't need an angular filter for that, use a standard, native javascript filter...

```
list.filter(x => !x.correctChoiceIds.length);
```

Comment: This one also works but I don't understand quite understand the syntax. I am still a beginner.

Comment: @riyu you can have a look at the docs for [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and for [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as well, but basically you are filtering all the items in your list which have an empty `correctChoiceIds` array (`x.correctChoiceIds.length === 0`, 0 is a falsy value in javascript, that's why I negate the condition with the `!`). Hope now it is more clear ;)